# HackerRank Sparse Arrays Challenge C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

There is a collection of input strings and a collection of query strings. For each query string, determine how many times it occurs in the list of input strings. Return an array of the results.

**Function Description**

The function matchingStrings must return an array of integers representing the frequency of occurrence of each query string in strings.

matchingStrings has the following parameters:

string strings[n] - an array of strings to search
string queries[q] - an array of query strings

**Returns**

int[q]: an array of results for each query

**Solution**

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "4", "aba", "baba", "aba", "xzxb" };
List<string> queries = new List<string> { "3", "aba", "xzxb", "ab" }; 

List<int> outputList = Result.matchingStrings(strings, queries);

for (int i = 0; i < outputList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(outputList[i]);
}

public class Result
{
    public static List<int> matchingStrings(List<string> strings, List<string> queries)
    {
        int inputCount = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(strings[0], out inputCount);
        string[] input = strings.GetRange(1, strings.Count - 1).ToArray();
        var stringsMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputCount; i++)
        {
            if (stringsMap.ContainsKey(input[i]))
            {
                stringsMap[input[i]]++;
            }
            else
            {
                stringsMap.Add(input[i], 1);
            }   
        }
  
        int queryCount = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(queries[0], out queryCount);
        string[] queryStrings = queries.GetRange(1, queries.Count - 1).ToArray();
        int[] output = new int[queryCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < queryCount; i++)
        {
            if (stringsMap.ContainsKey(queryStrings[i]))
            {
                output[i] = stringsMap[queryStrings[i]];
            }
        }

        List<int> outputList = output.ToList();

        return outputList;
    }
}
```

The code works fine for the given sample input in VS code.  However, when it is inserted into the HackerRank online IDE, it returns no output.   I do not understand what the problem could be.

Comment: The template solution does not pass an integer as the first element.

Comment: You may be right about that.  I will look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is my 100% solution in C#:

```
List<int> res = new List<int>();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<queries.Count; i++) {
    count=0;
    foreach(string s in strings) {
    if(queries[i] == s) {
    count++;
     }
    }
    res.Add(count);
    }
    return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution in python

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
hash_map=dict()

results=[]
for str in strings:
    if str in hash_map:
        hash_map[str]+=1
    else:
        hash_map[str]=1
for q in queries:
    if q in hash_map:
        results.append(hash_map[q])
    else:
        results.append(0)

return results
```

Comment: This question is for C#, though.

Comment: I figured you'd be able to make the translation

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<int> matchingStrings(List<string> strings, List<string> queries)
{
    int count = 0;
    List<int> countOfOccurences = new List<int>();
    foreach(var query in queries){
        count = strings.Where(x => x == query).Count();
        countOfOccurences.Add(count);
    }       
    return countOfOccurences;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).